# typo3 change default header with custom field?

Tags: typo3

i created a totally new Content Element type with extension kickstarter. I created new header field and dont use the default header field.

The problem now is: in the backend, in the list or normally page, the listing of my content elements are "default + plugin name". How to change this that it takes entry from my custom header input?

thank you, Peter

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [a hook](http://doxygen.frozenkiwi.com/typo3/html/de/dbd/interfacetx__cms__layout__tt__content__drawItemHook.html) of the page module like `tt_news` does it.

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['cms/layout/class.tx_cms_layout.php']['list_type_Info']['9']['tt_news'] = 'EXT:tt_news/lib/class.tx_ttnews_cms_layout.php:tx_ttnews_cms_layout->getExtensionSummary';
```